# themed bootstrap causing problems in rails app devise and other view files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2

rails application which using gems like devise,cancan now not storing some session based values like who created , created by after applying themed bootstrap directly into application.some of the view directories appeared twice. which themed bootstrap is best for rails application?